# What's a verb that indicates a change from public to private?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need this for a user-interface label on a button that changes a document's status from publicly visible to privately visible, meaning that it can thereafter only be seen by the creator and by administrative users. One idea I had was "hide", but that seemed to give the wrong connotation. When I searched for a term, the only one I found was "privatize", but that has a completely different context.

Example Usage:

> Share Report *(Private -> Pending)*
>
> Approve Report *(Pending -> Public)*
>
> [Hide]* Report *(Public -> Private)*

Comment: **Unpublish** should work

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but these documents are not being "published".

Comment: *Withdraw* from public access.

Comment: @HotLicks thank you, that's a good one! It also matches because these documents would explicitly have to have been made public in order for that option to be available.

Comment: Why is **hide** not okay? Facebook uses "hide" to restrict visibility of photos you're tagged in.

Comment: @NVZ "hide" is not something I wanted to use because, on facebook for example, it implies that you want to prevent someone from viewing it because it is somehow bad. This option is not intended for documents that are inherently illegitimate, it's just for documents that aren't considered necessary for everyone to view.

Comment: If this is your metaphor "privatize", as some would do to the post office or Amtrak, is a word.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts "Publish" and "unpublish" have fairly standard secondary meanings online, via the blogging world, of making public or non-public.

Comment: How about **reverse**?

Comment: @ChrisSunami I'm aware of the commonality of "(un)publish" online, but it just doesn't fit in this context.

Comment: @HotLicks Great minds think alike :)  For the record, your comment hadn't posted yet when I started my answer...

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Requests to help name something are out of scope.
Questions that invite many equally valid answers are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: Camouflage? Cloak?  Adumbrate? Encache? Discombobulate?

Comment: Most websites use the phrase "make private."

Comment: @ChrisSunami - No biggie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Withdraw** Report

> to take (something) back so that it is no longer available
>   to remove from use or cultivation
>   - http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/withdraw

If you were just moving back to pending status, you could use "unapprove" to denote that you are reversing a previous step, but since you are moving it all the way back, I would go with "withdraw" to imply that you are both unapproving *and* unsharing.

Answer (score 2):

**Conceal** - [M.W.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conceal)

> *Verb*
> To place out of sight.
>
> "*The files were public, but they have been concealed.*"
> "*The defendant is accused of attempting to conceal evidence.*"

Answer (score 2):

**Retract** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retract)

> *verb* 2.a. take back, withdraw
>
> *"retract a confession"*
> *"Their college grants were retracted."*
> *"They retracted the job offer"*

Comment: A retraction is a *public* declaration that the document is inoperative (to borrow a term from one of Richard Nixon's flacks).  I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

**Unpublish** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unpublish)

> *verb* [with object]
> Make (content that has previously been published online) unavailable to the public
>
> *"the magazine first amended and then unpublished the article"*
> *"In an emergency, you can always unpublish a post that may have seen enough comments or had enough reads."*
> *"Both The New York Times and The Washington Post have policies establishing that they generally do not unpublish accurate articles."*

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as unpublish on the internet.  Once it's out there it's out there.  What you can do is:

**Restrict access**

> Restrict
>
> verb (used with object)
>
> 1. to confine or keep within limits, as of space, action, choice, intensity, or quantity.

This doesn't mean that those private pictures in that document are no longer out there.  It means you're no longer handing them out.

Since it really works this way, don't use words that imply it works another way.